# Update and delete data in database using datagridview

Tags: c#

```
 try
 {         
      TblProduct product = new TblProduct();
      product.Description = textBox1.Text;
      product.Price = decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text);
      product.Image = imagedata;
      product.ProductType = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
      msd.AddToTblProducts(product);
      msd.SaveChanges();
      Msgbox mg = new Msgbox();
      mg.ShowDialog();
 }
 catch (Exception err)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
 }
```

I want to delete and update data using datagridview. How do I do this?

Comment: i use this code to insert data to data database

Comment: Welcome th stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started, inside of your *Grid* you would attach a button.  Since I'm not sure if your utilizing Model View Controller, Web Forms, or another aspect I'll default to Web Forms. For instance:

```
<asp:LinkButton id='btnEdit-<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server"
     CommandName="Delete"
     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")'
     OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
     Tooltip='<%# String.Format("Delete Record: {0}", Eval("Id")) %>' />
```

So the following button provides an argument name, when we push to code behind the `CommandArgument` value will now be accessible based on the *Grid Id*.  That is what the `Eval` is exposing for us.

On the code behind, you would have the following:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var id = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument as int?;
}
```

Inside the brackets the following occurs:

- Instantiation
- Retrieve the value in the `CommandArgument`
- Casting as an `int?`

The instantiation is important to access the control, the `CommandArgument` has our value, the `int?` will provide a clean fail safe if it can't cast.  It in essence will be `null` if it fails.  Which is easy to work with.

Once you have said `Id` you can call your database and actually perform desired query.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                if (rowId > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                    var toBeDeleted = msd.TblProducts.First(c => c.ProductID == rowId);
                    msd.TblProducts.DeleteObject(toBeDeleted);
                    msd.SaveChanges();
                    productdelete ps = new productdelete();
                    ps.ShowDialog();
                }

Comment: i use above method to delete and now my problem is ow to update.im developing windows form application in c# using service based database.and entity model

Comment: Well, the same can be used for an update.  The only variation would be in the database call.  How are you updating?  Directly on the Grid or do you call another popup with separate controls?

Comment: i need to update directly from the grid and .the data should save to the database.but in my table there is field for image .how can i update image through data grid without picture box;